# Inserting array into mysql in correct columns

Tags: php, arrays

Im totally new to php but this should be easy for you. 
I have changeable number pair of forms (using jquery) sending data to process page. 
I manage to capture data with following code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $formName => $value)
 echo "The  ".htmlspecialchars($formName)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
```

Since the data is coming from a pair of forms(called VALUE and QUANTITY), I get this result for instance if I have two pairs:

```
The VALUE is 120
the QUANTITY is 80

The VALUE is 150
The QUANTITY is 50
```

Question: 
How can I insert these data into corresponding columns VALUE,QUANTITY?

I tried with following code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $valor) {

$q_MySQL_Array = "INSERT INTO tickets (VALUE) VALUES ('$value')";
$MySQL_Array = mysql_query($q_MySQL_Array) or die (mysql_error());
```

But I only manage to insert into same column both values.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: use $valor in place of ('$value') here